# Azure: how to compare dates in a policy

Tags: azure, tags, policy

I am trying to implement a policy in Azure to delete snapshot after 15 days have passed, for this I need to compare dates, I am using tags but my policy is not properly configured as the resources being evaluated are marked as compliant, when both resources tags have different dates, 1 should be marked as non-compliant, I am thinking I am not comparing the date as I should

here is my policy definition

```
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "snapshot-deletion-test",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "All",
    "description": "this is a policy which will delete all the snapshots older than 15 days, this is the first test, only checks the snapshots on the HCE-general-RG resource group which is under hce-chq-sandbox-nonprod sub",
    "metadata": {
      "createdBy": "ce5c7636-f9a1-462a-9c8f-7ff7f679d813",
      "createdOn": "2023-10-23T22:17:16.7301903Z",
      "updatedBy": "c...",
      "updatedOn": "2023-10-25T18:56:07.1594354Z"
    },
    "parameters": {},
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allof": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "microsoft.compute/snapshots"
          },
          {
            "field": "tags['timeCreated']",
            "greaterOrEquals": "addDays(utcNow(),1)"
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "audit"
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "/...",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
  "name": "...",
  "systemData": {
    "createdBy": "Samuel....",
    "createdByType": "User",
    "createdAt": "2023-10-23T22:17:16.6801294Z",
    "lastModifiedBy": "Samuel....",
    "lastModifiedByType": "User",
    "lastModifiedAt": "2023-10-25T18:56:07.0443867Z"
  }
}
```

as you can see, the policy rule has this evaluation
"greaterOrEquals": "addDays(utcNow(),1)", which supposed to check if the date and tag timeCreated is equal to today or 1 day more in the future will be marked as compliant

this is 1 of the 2 resources being evaluated and that is marked as true
[image]

maybe I am not comparing with the proper date format or is something else in the policy.

any help is well appreciated